# Sencha CSS variable overwrite ignored

Tags: css, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sass, compass-sass

I want to remove the button default stroke in Sencha Touch 2.2.

```
$button-stroke-weight : 0px ;
```

When I compile the following file with compass I get "identical" and there are no actual changes in the theme.

```
$button-stroke-weight : 0px ;

$base-gradient: 'flat';

@import 'sencha-touch/default';
@import 'sencha-touch/default/all';

// Custom code goes here..

@include sencha-button-ui('positive', #8AB24F, 'flat');
@include sencha-button-ui('negative', #888888, 'flat');

@include icon('mail');
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with a `compass clean` and then a `compass compile`?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: This provide an answer instead. Compass sometime requires to clean its cache to build a valid CSS. So doing a clean before a compile sometimes is enough to fix a problem.